# More than one project was found in the current working directory. Use the --project option

Tags: entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side

I am new in all this ( Azure and programming in general ) and this error was driving me crazy all day yesterday.

[image: Web app deployment screen]
What I tried :

Deleting all the migrations and database, than add-migration initial and everything seems fine locally

Comment: What error? Post the error *text* as *text* in the question itself. What you posted in the title is produced when you try to run a tool in the wrong folder, or, as the error says, there are multiple `csproj` files in the same folder. It has nothing to do with EF Core.

Comment: In fact, why would multiple `csproj` files be in the same directory?

Comment: " there are multiple csproj files in the same folder. "

I have opened the project directly on my disk and there were multiple csproj, they were some backups made by "source tree" probably because I do not know how to use it fully yet. There like you said, so the problem is solved.

Thank you very much.

How do I set the post as solved? Just edit the title or there is some other function?

Comment: Source Tree doesn't create "backups". It's a git client. There may have been conflicts which weren't resolved and both the local and remote files were kept